# como poner un foreach dentro de un while

Tags: php, while, foreach

```
    $query4 = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT s.e_mail
                             FROM staff_courses as sc join
                             staff as s
                             on(s.id_staff = sc.id_staff)
                             WHERE sc.id_course = 'C4-1' and sc.roll_staff_course = 'Coordinator'");

while ($valores3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query4)) {
  $aremail = $valores3['e_mail']; 

            foreach ($aremail as $email) {
                echo $email;
        }
```

Comment: No estás describiendo tu problema bien. No se sabe cómo están almacenados los datos en el campo s.e_mail de la base de datos. Suponiendo que son correos separados por comas `"correo1@domain1.com,correo2@domain2.com,...etc"` entonces tienes que convertir el string en array antes de pasarlo por el `foreach`, con la instrucción `explode(',', $valores3['e_mail']);`

Comment: hola muchas gracias por tu comentario, entonces si al realizar esta operacion se convierte automaticamnete en un array?

$array = array($valores3['e_mail']);